# React Native: Does updating a ListView dataSource through setState rerender the whole component?

Tags: javascript, facebook, listview, reactjs, react-native

If I update the dataSource of a ListView by using this.setState({dataSource: blabla}), will this trigger a rerender of the whole component? I only want to change the data in the ListView and I don't want to compute an expensive rerender again.

Comment: I think it will re-render. But re-rendering isn't supposed to be very expensive if it has only one small change. Because it only re-renders the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will **seem** like the whole app re-renders. But re-rendering isn't supposed to be expensive if it has only one small change. Because it only re-renders the changes.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html